# Как использовать API склонения падежа словосочетаний?

Tags: json, api, php

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть [**API для склонения по падежу словосочетаний на русском языке**](https://github.com/summerisgone/pyphrasy) 
***Пример url для запроса внизу страницы после заголовка Веб-Сервис***).
Вот только как его правильно применить не понимаю.

**Пробую вот такую конструкцию:**

```
$url_in = 'http://pyphrasy.herokuapp.com/inflect?phrase=слово&cases=gent&cases=datv';
$fp = file_get_contents($url_in);
if (!$fp) {
    $title_enc = $myroc['title'];
} else {
    $title_enc = json_decode($fp, true);
}
print_r($title_enc);
```

Выводит: Array ( [datv] => слову [orig] => слово [gent] => слова )

Но самое важное это получить словосочетание, но если отправляю словосочетание запрос зависает. А на прямую по ссылке обращаюсь все работает причем быстро! Что такое Подскажите.

Comment: @VenZell ...может это все же из-за file_get_contents?

Comment: @misc ... зависает - ответ долго не приходит... потом обрубается сервером по той же причине

Comment: @cheh1, проверьте скорость доступа к сайту с другого компьютера.  
Вряд ли проблема в скрипте. У меня запросы выполняются моментально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$phrase = urlencode('другое слово');

$url_in = "http://pyphrasy.herokuapp.com/inflect?phrase={$phrase}&cases=gent&cases=datv";
$fp = file_get_contents($url_in);
if (!$fp) {
    $title_enc = $myroc["title"];
} else {
    $title_enc = json_decode($fp, true);
}
print_r($title_enc);

# Выведет: 
# Array ( [datv] => другому слову [orig] => другое слово [gent] => другого слова )
```

Не забывайте кодировать словосочетание с помощью urlencode

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, вроде работает:

```
<?
$url_in = 'http://pyphrasy.herokuapp.com/inflect?phrase=слово&cases=gent&cases=datv';
$fp = file_get_contents($url_in); if (!$fp) {$title_enc = $myroc['title'];} else {$title_enc = json_decode($fp, true);} 
// выводит слову
$sklonenie = $title_enc['datv'];
?>
```

Comment: @cheh1, используйте urlencode или делаете replace пробелов на %20